# Distributing lists on a snow cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply

The snow package parXapply() functions distribute work very well when data is only contained in one list or matrix, but in this case I need to run a function on four different types of matrices.

For example, this is what I have now:

```
res.list = parLapply(cl, mynames, myfun, listA, listB, listC, listD)

myfun = function(name, listA, listB, listC, listD) {
  matrixA = listA[[name]]
  matrixB = listB[[name]]
  matrixC = listC[[name]]
  matrixD = listD[[name]]
}
```

The problem I am having is that the matrices are very large and I suspect calling parLapply() on the full lists involves transferring all the data to each cluster node. This can be very time-consuming and reduces the cluster performances.

How can I split the lists before calling myfun() and only send the relevant matrices to each node for processing?

Comment: Looks like mapply() is what I need but it's not available in snow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clusterMap() does the job:

```
res.list = clusterMap(cl, myfun, mynames, listA, listB, listC, listD)
```

Somehow the parMapply() wrapper was left out of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given by Robert Kubrick best answers this question using `clusterMap`. However, I think other people searching for an answer to a related question may benefit from another option -- `mcmapply` (which is the multi-core version of `mapply`). For example:

```
mcmapply(rep, 1:4, 4:1)
```

`mcmapply` implements a parallel `mapply` using forking, which means that it is **not an option on Windows machines.** Moreover, there can be complications if you're running R within a GUI. By the way, there is also an `mclapply` that is the multi-core version of `lapply`.

So `mcmapply` and `mclapply` are the simplest versions of what you might otherwise expect to be called `parMapply` and `parLapply`.